# Can't see "Fonts provided by application" in plist in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am trying to add an external font to my iOS application.
I went to add an entry to the plist file, but when I checked, the section for "Fonts provided by application" isn't present.

Is this feature implemented differently in Xcode 5?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add "Fonts provided by application" in the plist yourself, first by adding a new field, selecting the proper category and adding your font name.

Keep in mind that selection is case sensitive.

1.Create new list by pressing the `+` symbol

[image]

2.Type capital `F`

[image]

Comment: No wonder I just can't find it.Case sensitive is the the key to get it.